# cordova :Exception: Property 'requestFileSystem' of object [object global] is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

i use visual studio with cordova to try a create a file with javascript but i receive every time this error "Exception: Property 'requestFileSystem' of object [object global] is not a function"

this is my code:

```
function createFile() {
    var type =window.PERSISTENT;
    var size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;



    window.requestFileSystem(type , 0, successCallback, errorCallback)

    function successCallback(fs) {
        fs.root.getFile('test.txt', { create: true, exclusive: true }, function (fileEntry) {
            alert('File creation successfull!')
        }, errorCallback);
    }

    function errorCallback(error) {
        alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
    }

}
```

Comment: could you post your complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you properly installed cordova-plugin-file. Run follwoing in your console:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

You can get more insights from this document:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Comment: how do you build your app?

Comment: ty for your help , at the end i have uninstalled the plugin,  after i have reinstalled it ty so much